# adding group membership as a node attribute after simulating a network in iGraph

Tags: r, matrix, attributes, igraph

I created a simulated network (via SBM) the `igraph` package in R:

```
    library(igraph)
    pr_mat <- cbind(c(0.5,0.001), c(0.001, 0.5))
    g <- sample_sbm(10, pref.matrix = pr_mat, block.sizes = c(5,5), 
                    directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
```

The adjacency matrix of graph `g` confirms that nodes 1-5 are considered one group, and nodes 6-10 are considered another group.

```
> as_adj(g)
 [1,] . 1 . 1 . . . . . .
 [2,] 1 . 1 1 . . . . . .
 [3,] . 1 . 1 1 . . . . .
 [4,] 1 1 1 . 1 . . . . .
 [5,] . . 1 1 . . . . . .
 [6,] . . . . . . 1 1 . 1
 [7,] . . . . . 1 . 1 1 1
 [8,] . . . . . 1 1 . 1 .
 [9,] . . . . . . 1 1 . 1
[10,] . . . . . 1 1 . 1 .
```

But the resulting igraph object produced by my `sample_sbm` call doesn't include group membership as a vertex attribute.

```
> g
IGRAPH 8750fb0 U--- 10 15 -- Stochastic block-model
+ attr: name (g/c), loops (g/l)
+ edges from 8750fb0:
 [1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 1-- 4 2-- 4 3-- 4 3-- 5 4-- 5 6-- 7 6-- 8 7-- 8 7-- 9 8-- 9 6--10 7--10 9--10
```

How can I add this info for plotting and analysis?

Comment: Sorry - in what second column? I do that as well when when I have an empirical net. To be clear, `as_adj(g)` is just me outputting the adjacency matrix to show that the group membership is unambiguous...it's not a place where I try to assign node attributes or anything. And I need to use `sample_sbm()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sampled graph contains two distinct components with no shared edges (as in the example you provide), then you can use `components()$membership` to get group membership and assign it to a node attribute:

```r
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)

pr_mat <- cbind(c(0.5,0.001), c(0.001, 0.5))
g <- sample_sbm(10, pref.matrix = pr_mat, block.sizes = c(5,5), 
                directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)

V(g)$group <- components(g)$membership

plot(g, vertex.color = V(g)$group)
```

[image]

This only works because the preference matrix you provide creates two distinct components. If there are edges between the blocks then obviously there is only one component in the graph. In that case, you can use one of the `cluster_*()` functions:

```r
set.seed(1234)

pr_mat <- cbind(c(0.5,0.1), c(0.1, 0.5))
g <- sample_sbm(10, pref.matrix = pr_mat, block.sizes = c(5,5), 
                directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)

V(g)$group <- cluster_louvain(g)$membership

plot(g, vertex.color = V(g)$group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>